# Kubenetes jenkins deployment get failed, got "Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503" error

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster in Digital Ocean and I am using this Jenkins deploy.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins-server
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
        runAsUser: 1000
      serviceAccountName: jenkins-admin
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "2Gi"
            cpu: "700m"
          requests:
            memory: "500Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - name: httpport
          containerPort: 8080
        - name: jnlpport
          containerPort: 50000
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: "/login"
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 90
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          failureThreshold: 5
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: "/login"
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          failureThreshold: 3
        volumeMounts:
        - name: jenkins-data
          mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
      volumes:
      - name: jenkins-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: jenkins-pv-claim
```

The deploy is created without problems but I am seeing this error.

Normal   Created    25m                kubelet            Created container jenkins
Normal   Started    25m                kubelet            Started container jenkins
Warning  Unhealthy  24m (x4 over 24m)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503

not sure what is happend.